# scope accessible rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, scope, routes

I have this scope:

```
scope ":user_id", :as => "user" do 
 resources :boards,  :controller => 'users/boards'
end
```

I get this route:

```
http://localhost/hyperrjas/boards/
```

I want a url without **boards** then on **routes.rb** I add:

```
scope ":user_id", :as => "user" do 
 resources :boards,  :controller => 'users/boards', :path => '/'
end
```

**That works great, but it is still accessible via "/boards" ... How do I prevent that? (I'm using Rails 3.1)**

Comment: have you tried adding :except => [:index] to the end of your resources line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't have to specify the controller names when using resources and in this caseI would use nested resources:

```
resource :user, only: :show do
  resources :boards
end
```

This should give you the following:

- /:user_id
- /:user_id/boards
- /:user_id/boards/new
- /:user_id/boards/:id/
- /:user_id/boards/:id/edit

and of course your restful routes!